# 分かるやつにしてよ meaning

Tags: translation

I was reading Bilingual news (in Japanese and English). One topic in the podcast touches on the decling birth rate and aging population in Japan. In this context a discussion about nuclear families crops up, where the American presenter mentions the old TV show full house. The following exchange takes place.

> Michael: I thought there was some boy.
>
> Mami: えっ?
>
> Michael: Am I totally...
>
> Mami: うそだ.
>
> Michael: I'm not a Full House expert, but...
>
> Mami: じゃあ, 何でフルハウスを選んだの, 今?分かるやつにしてよ.
>
> Michael: But it's kind of interesting, you know, like the family size that ends up on TV. It's kind of an archetype of our society.

My question is what does Mami mean by 分かるやつにしてよ? It sounds like, 'Become an expert!' but that seems an odd reading. So, what is she saying?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

She's saying "pick something you know about."

She's using the verb する which obviously doesn't mean "pick/choose" but する can sometimes be used vaguely like this. In this case translating literally might be something like "do this (the thing we are talking about) with a thing you know"

Comment: #4 on 大辞林 https://kotobank.jp/word/%E7%82%BA%E3%82%8B-544032#E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.9E.97.20.E7.AC.AC.E4.B8.89.E7.89.88